# Trying to change on_click function to a timer of 30 seconds

Tags: python, loops, timer, onclick, screenshot

i am trying to make a loop that screenshots every 30 seconds and saves it in a folder

This is what I have now:

```
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global path
    if pressed:
        takeScreenshoot(path)
        print('ScreenShoot Taken')
```

iv'e tried a bunch of different codes but couldnt get it work

Comment: A new thread will be needed to take the screenshots to not hang the ui(Not Responding) and maybe use time.sleep(30)

Comment: Which library are you using?